# Issue in bcrypt and async

Tags: node.js, lambda, bcrypt

I am trying to write a create user form. In my lambda function. I want to try if bcrypt is working or not so I add something like this:

```
...
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
...
exports.handler = async (event, error, callback) => {
  const email = event.email ? event.email : ''
  const username = event.username ? event.username : ''
  const password = event.password ? event.password : '' // in this example,I use '123123' as a test password
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime().toString()
  ...
  const saltRounds = 10
  const passwordhash = await bcrypt.hashSync(password, saltRounds)
  console.log('passwordhash' , passwordhash)
  const compareResult = await bcrypt.compareSync(passwordhash , password)
  console.log('compateresult' ,compareResult )
```

But I dont know why in compareResult . It always returns false.
I have read some others question which is aslo having the same problem and it said I should use await and let it run. However I still cannot fix it. Can anyone explain that how does bcrypt.hashSync and bcrypt.compareSync run?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt), the password is the first parameter for `compareSync`. It works as it is expected if I change the parameter order in your code.

```js
const compareResult = await bcrypt.compareSync(password, passwordhash)
```

Also you can remove the `await`, both `compareSync` and `hashSync` are synchronous methods.

Comment: Yea...I also found that I just made a stupid mistake and it took me for an hr...